# Multithreading : the best way when write duplicated data

Tags: java, multithreading, oracle, performance

I use Spring, Java, Ibatis, Oracle.
I have 1 job which use multithreading to process a lot of data.

All threads will writing data to the same tables inside database, but some time the data of the threads are the same by contraint, like that :

```
CONSTRAINT n_uc1 UNIQUE (name, title, language, ...)
```

. The example code like that :

```
public Long write(Input input) {
        Long key = read(input);
        if (key != null)
        {
            return key;
        }

        try
        {
            key = write(input);
        }
        catch (org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException ex)
        {
            // if exception happend, it means already wrote data, read it again
            key = read(input);
        }
        return key;
    }
```

With this code, I can get which I expected, but some time I got the exception, and it make the performance go down.

The rule are :

- I can't update schema
- I don't want to use synchronized, because it make the performance go down

**Do you have any other solution for this ? 
The performance is very important point.**

Comment: look this:https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/72501/duplicate-key-violates-unique-constraint-when-using-multi-threading

Comment: Thanks @AmolRaje , But I can't update schema, It means I can't create a stored procedure . Any other idea ?

Comment: *"Performance is very important"* but you can't change the most important factor governing database performance? Sad.

Answer (score 1):

The description seems to be very vague but still attempting to answer.

If synchronization or removing the constraint is not an option, you may consider how you are feeding the data to the threads.

From the description what i understood is, sometimes more than 1 thread pick up the same data for processing.

If that is the case, you may come up with some logic to distribute the input data among threads than let the threads pick up input data randomly.

If you can give information about input data, its easy to give a solution